# Android: ADB install issue, Could not allocate in memory

Tags: android, installation, adb, assets, ram

Hi i'm trying to install an APK with 2 GB size to a device with 1 GB RAM. I'm guessing that's because you can't allocate 2 GB inside 1 GB. I only want to confirm if this right because I don't how adb install works, but the common sense tells me I'm right... Is the first time I deal with this issue.

Comment: Don't do that, deliver the huge content after installation.

Comment: Yeah I know, it just that we are experimenting with a project. What is the APK size that you would recommend? or do you recommend only classes, libraries and icons inside the apk?

Answer (score 0):

RAM is where program runs. APK resides in phone memory (or) SD card. May be that size is not enough.  If it is RAM issue you will see runtime errors.

Comment: Free device memory is around 9.55 GB but still cannot install. Could not allocate in memory still appearing